# referencing a movieclip symbol on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I am sure this is a very basic question but I just could not find out how it is done (all tutorials I read have this step skipped).

I am working on Adobe Flash CS4, AS3. I have a movieclip symbol on stage, and I have assigned it with an instance name "myClip".

Then, on frame 10, I want to change its position, say,

```
myClip.x = 10;
```

but I only got an error message "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." What have I missed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check on the timeline that the MovieClip is available on frame 10. Also, double check it has an instance name on that frame (it's possible you named it on an earlier frame but the instance on frame 10 is not named).

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, it is as simple as that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on timeline myClip layer on frame 10 right click >> insertframe..